# Actionscript 3, rotate object on drag

Tags: actionscript, rotation, drag

I have an object I need to rotate by clicking and dragging. Following some AS2 code I got the object to rotate a bit every time the mouse is clicked, but can't get it to work with drag.

```
needle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_2);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_2);

function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

        var angle = Math.atan2(mouseY-needle.y,mouseX-needle.x);
        // apply rotation to handle by converting angle into degrees
        needle.rotation = angle*180/Math.PI;
        // rotate the grip opposite the handle so it won't rotate along with it
        //this.grip._rotation = -this._rotation;
}

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    needle.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem I see is that the `MOUSE_DOWN` event only fires once per click, so you only run the code in the handler once.

There could be a better way than this but this is how I'd consider doing it:

EDITED FOR DETAIL:

```
public class Test extends MovieClip {
    private var n:Needle;

    public function Test() {
        // constructor code
        n = new Needle();

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownF,false,0,true);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUpF,false,0,true);


        n.x = stage.stageWidth/2; //center needle on stage
        n.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        addChild(n); //add needle to stage
    }
    public function mouseDownF(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,rotate,false,0,true);
    }
    public function rotate(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var angle:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - n.y,mouseX - n.x); //get angle in radians (pythagoras) 

        angle = angle * 180/Math.PI -90; //convert to degrees , the 90 is to have it point to the mouse

        n.rotation = angle; //rotate
    }
    public function mouseUpF(e:MouseEvent):void {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,rotate);
    }
}
```

So when the user clicks down (`mouseDown`) it activates an event listener that fires the `rotate` handler every time the mouse moves. When the user lets go of the click the event listener is destroyed. The `false,0,true);` when adding the event listener is to make it a [weakly referenced listener](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html) so that it gets collected by the garbage collector and doesn't just sit in memory taking up space forever.

Comment: Hmm thanks it improved a bit bot not much. The needle MC snaps to different angles and doesn't move with the mouse. when I click and drag, the MC snaps to a new rotation and if I move the mouse some more it snaps to a new position. Also it only rotates clockwise.

Comment: It might have something to do with the rotation of my MC. The symbol is pointing to the right.

Comment: Nope still not working, does not follow mouse only snaps to a new angle. Anyone?

Comment: Still a little jerky but I've tested the code that I've added to my answer and it works.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot :) Worked  perfectly. Starting to wish I had paid more attention in math class growing up.